# Keeping table thead 1st row and tbody 1st column fixed scrolling horizontal scrollbar flickering issue in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm facing an issue in CSS and jQuery. I have created one table in html keeping table thead first row and tbody first column fixed, the remaining table cell should scroll horizontally. The scroll bar for table while scrolling in IE tbody first column start flickering issue but in Chrome it works properly. Please help me.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var isIE11 = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);
            var customScroller;
            if (isIE11)
                customScroller = function () {
                    $('thead th').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //if using IE11, fix the th element 
                };
            else
                customScroller = function () {
                    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //if not using IE11, fix the thead element
                };

            $('tbody').scroll(function (e) { //detect a scroll event on the tbody
                /*
                Setting the thead left value to the negative valule of tbody.scrollLeft will make it track the movement
                of the tbody element. Setting an elements left value to that of the tbody.scrollLeft left makes it maintain             it's relative position at the left of the table.    
                */
                customScroller(); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
                $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft());
                //fix the first cell of the header
                $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
            });
        });
```

```css
        table {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
/*thead*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  overflow: visible;
}
thead th
        {
            min-width: 159px;
            height: 32px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            vertical-align: top !important;
        }
thead th:nth-child(1) {/*first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the first cell in the header from the header*/
}
/*tbody*/
tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the tbody from the header*/
  overflow: scroll;
}
tbody td
        {
            min-width: 159px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  /*the first cell in each tr*/
  position:relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the first column from the tbody*/
  height: 44px;
  background: #f0f0f0 !important;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <table style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; display:block;">
      <thead style="position:relative; display:block;">
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
          <th>Header 5</th>
          <th>Header 6</th>
          <th>Header 7</th>
          <th>Header 8</th>
          <th>Header 9</th>
          <th>Header 10</th>
          <th>Header 11</th>
          <th>Header 12</th>
          <th>Header 13</th>
          <th>Header 14</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="max-height:600px;position:relative; display:block;">
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
              <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please using below working table

```js
// requires jquery library
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');   
 });
```

```css
.table-scroll {
 position:relative;
 max-width:600px;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.table-wrap {
 width:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}
.table-scroll table {
 width:100%;
 margin:auto;
 border-collapse:separate;
 border-spacing:0;
}
.table-scroll th, .table-scroll td {
 padding:5px 10px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#fff;
 white-space:nowrap;
 vertical-align:top;
}
.table-scroll thead, .table-scroll tfoot {
 background:#f9f9f9;
}
.clone {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 pointer-events:none;
}
.clone th, .clone td {
 visibility:hidden
}
.clone td, .clone th {
 border-color:transparent
}
.clone tbody th {
 visibility:visible;
 color:red;
}
.clone .fixed-side {
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#eee;
 visibility:visible;
}
.clone thead, .clone tfoot{background:transparent;}
```

```html
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 6</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 7</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content<br>
            test</td>
          <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">&nbsp;</th>
          <td>Footer 2</td>
          <td>Footer 3</td>
          <td>Footer 4</td>
          <td>Footer 5</td>
          <td>Footer 6</td>
          <td>Footer 7</td>
          <td>Footer 8</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What problem you are facing in making it dynamic?

Comment: i'm facing problem in ie tbody 1st column is  flickering while scrolling table before i sent one example same issue i'm facing in ie